# Runtime error: Cannot find control with name: '1'

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, ionic3

I use HTTP request to get the list of items in ionViewDidLoad(). I want to display a list of item with plus and minus sign with an input box in between. Each of the item consists of 'id' and 'name' field. I would like to use 'id' of each of the items to differentiate when it's being submitted. How do I declare ***formControlName*** in input tag as each of the item's id?

[image]

```
<ion-item  *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ion-label fixed>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
  <ion-icon item-end name="remove-circle" (click)="decreaseAmount(item.id)"></ion-icon>
  <input item-end placeholder="Quantity" type="tel" formControlName={{item.id}} 
      (click)="changeAmount(item.id, 'item.id')" ion-text text-center [style.width]="'50px'"/>
  <ion-icon item-end name="add-circle" (click)="increaseAmount(item.id)"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

inside TS file

```
this.itemForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  items:this.getItems()
});
```

this.getItems() will return

> [[id:1, name:Apple],[id:2, name: Mango]...]

***UPDATE:***

I managed to use item.id as the name for the input but how do I declare each of the item's id in this._formBuilder.group?? When I manually add it will work, but in the real life application, I won't be knowing how many items will there be.

```
this.itemForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      items:this.getItems(),
      1:[0, Validators.required],
      2:[0, Validators.required],
      3:[0, Validators.required],
      4:[0, Validators.required],
      5:[0, Validators.required],
      6:[0, Validators.required],
      7:[0, Validators.required],
      8:[0, Validators.required],
    });
```

Comment: You want the attribute values for the input fields to be 1, 2.. etc based on the item ids in the response?

Comment: not the attribute values, is the name of the input. I wan the formControlName to be 1,2...etc based on the item ids in the response

Comment: Example: <input placeholder="Quantity" type="tel" name="{{product.item.itemId}}" /> the name will be 1,2,3. Update the following in your template formControlName="{{item.id}}"

Comment: I tried to write formControlName="{{item.id}}" but will have this error -> Cannot find control with name: '1'

Comment: You can set the form builder field items using the item response from getItems. Check this link here dynamic input fields are created similar to how you have created them. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Have you wrapped ion-items inside form ?, Can you share some more code, like how you adding formcontrol when you click +

Comment: @Chellappanவ when click +, it is just increasing the quantity, not add one more field